# Printing ASCII Pyramid

Tags: c, ascii

I am trying to print the following ASCII Pyramid.

```
A B C D E F G F E D C B A
A B C D E F   F E D C B A 
A B C D E       E D C B A 
A B C D           D C B A 
A B C               C B A 
A B                   B A 
A                       A
```

But I am getting the following output:

```
A B C D E F G       F E D C B A
A B C D E F     F E D C B A 
A B C D E         E D C B A 
A B C D             D C B A 
A B C                 C B A 
A B                     B A 
A                         A
```

The first line is messed up. Can anyone help me to get the desired output?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <stdlib.h>;

void main() {
  unsigned long int x, y, z;
  printf("\nTHIS PROGRAM PRINTS ASCII PYRAMID \n");
  char c;
  y = 71;
  z = 12;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    for (int j = 65; j <= y; ++j) {
      printf("%c ", j); /*prints left side of the string */
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 2 * i; ++k) {

      printf("  "); /*prints spaces between the strings */
    }
    for (int l = y; l > 64; l--) {
      if (l == 71) {
        for (int p = 70; p > 64; p--)
          printf("%c ", i);
      } else
        printf("%c ", l); /* prints right part of the string */
    };
    y = y - 1;
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: your original: https://ideone.com/McocaK ... my 1st change: https://ideone.com/sXULtU ... my last change: https://ideone.com/DZoNKe

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two major problems in your code.

Firstly, you are printing one extra pair of 2 spaces between left and right characters.

Secondly, the

```
for (int p = 70; p > 64; p--)
  printf("%c ", i);
```

part is emitting junk (control characters) and extra spaces.

This program (with also minor fixes) seems working well.

```
/* remove extra semicolons */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* use standard return type */
int main() {
  unsigned long int x, y, z;
  printf("\nTHIS PROGRAM PRINTS ASCII PYRAMID \n");
  char c;
  y = 71;
  z = 12;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    for (int j = 65; j <= y; ++j) {
      printf("%c ", j); /*prints left side of the string */
    }

    /* reduce number or pairs of spaces to print */
    for (int k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; ++k) {

      printf("  "); /*prints spaces between the strings */
    }
    for (int l = y; l > 64; l--) {
      /* remove extra printing */
      if (l != 71)
        printf("%c ", l); /* prints right part of the string */
    };
    y = y - 1;
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; ++k)` can be simplified with `for (int k = 1; k < 2 * i ; ++k)` ^^ What about to recommend to replace 71 by 'G', 65 by 'A' etc ?

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT, it worked perfectly. It helped me improve my logic.